# App Engine Megacycles/sec per F1 instance

Tags: google-app-engine

Automatic instance scaling depends on various factors like number of concurrent requests, cpu utilization, etc.  I would like to be able to look at the App Engine dashboard and see which factor caused the number of instances to increase.

For cpu utilization, it is not clear what the comparison should be.  The dashboard presents cpu utilization in terms of Megacycles per second, but the autoscaling cpu utilization parameter is just a number between 0.5 and 0.95.

From [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard#instance_classes) an F1 instance apparently has a cpu limit of 600 MHz. This is frequency, not a cpu limit. Should I interpret this instead as a fully utilized F1 instance can hit 600 Megacycles per second?

And therefore, if I set a target_cpu_utilization = 0.5, I can expect autoscaling to increase the number of instances if the dashboard shows a cpu usage of more than 300 Megacycles/sec * # instances?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there are many factors that impact on the scaling on App Engine. There are three types of scaling that you can configure on your application, that will impact the way that it will be scaled. The three types are: **Automatic scaling**, **Basic Scaling** and **Manual scaling**.

I would recommend you to take a look at the documentation [How Instances are Managed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed). This documentation provides more insights on how the scaling occurs on App Engine.

Besides that, in the following articles, you can check for more information on how to configure and set the factors that control the scaling - which will be upscaled or not, etc. - that I believe should help you as well.

- [Designing for scale on App Engine standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/appengine-designing-for-scale)
- [app.yaml Configuration File](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: There is no mention in any of the provided links explaining how to convert Megacycles to MHz, which is what the question is asking.